# vTiger relationship between two custom modules not saving field data

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I created a relationship between two custom modules using the VGS Global Related Fields extension (https://www.vgsglobal.com/blog/vtiger-related-fields/). The relationship, list and field were created but I can't enter any data manually or using the search function. Clicking the magnifying glass icon will bring up the records from the related module but I can't select them - clicking on a record does nothing. Odd thing is that the problem is only between two custom modules. I used the same procedure to create a relationship between one of the custom modules and Organizations and that works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you inform VGS team about this issue? I think they will easily guide you on this. Or else you should explain the issue in detail here. You dint specify detail explanation, no screenshots etc.

Comment: Yes, opened a ticket with VGS over a week ago but no reply - free extension so not really expecting much support.